# How to Completely Teardown Flask App After Each Test in pytest?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am testing my Flask app using Pytest. I have 3 files

```
tests/
--conftest.py
--test_one.py
--test_two.py
```

If I run `test_one.py` **or** `test_two.py` using the following command, it will work without issue.

```
python -m pytest tests/test_one.py
```

The issue arises when I try to run all tests with the following command:

```
python -m pytest tests
```

I get this error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: serve_static
```

Im not actually surprised by this error since `init_app(app)` gets called twice (once per file) and I don't ever teardown the actual `app`.

My question is, **Is there a way to completely teardown a flask app and rebuild it for each individual test?** I am looking for the actual commands to do the tearing down (i.e. `app.teardown()`)

**Edit:** I am open to alternative ways of setting up a Flask app testing environment, if it would solve this problem (without creating new ones).

**Edit 2:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171254/flask-unit-testing-how-to-reset-app-url-map-for-each-test?rq=1) question. It is similar and would solve my problem but it involves importing inside a function. I suspect there has to be a better way.

**conftest.py**

```
import os
import pytest

from app import app, init_app
from config import TestConfig


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def client():

    app.config.from_object(TestConfig)

    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            init_app(app)
        yield client

    try:
        os.remove('tests/testing.db')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map._rules.clear()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def init_app(app):
    ...
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could include the code where `app` is being created.

Comment: @LuisOrduz - I added the pertinent parts of `app/__init__.py` where the `app` is created.

Comment: Anyone reading this: use the [pytest-flask](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-flask) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately my problem was how I created my `app`. Since it was created as a gloval variable in `__init__.py`, I could never *remake* it for each test. I refactored `__init__.py` (and the rest of my code) to use a `create_app` function where I could create the same app over and over again. The following code ended up working.

**app/__init__.py**

```
def create_app(config)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.url_map._rules.clear()
    from .models import db
    app.config.from_object(config)
    with app.app_context():

    return app

def init_app(app):
    ...
```

**conftest.py**

```
import os
import pytest

from app import create_app, init_app
from config import TestConfig


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def client():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.from_object(TestConfig)

    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            from app.models import db
            init_app(app, db)
            yield client

    try:
        os.remove('tests/testing.db')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a Class in each of your files which inherits TestCase. This way you can use the function `setup()` to generate your testclient as a Instance-Variable before each test. This way you can be sure that each test has the same environment to work with.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app import app as application

class TestApplication(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.client = application.app.test_client()

  def test_sth(self):
    r = self.client.get('/approute2sth')
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

  def test_sth_else(self):
    r = self.client.get('/approute2sth_else')
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: I am looking for the actual code to tear the flask app down so I can re-import or re-initialize without getting the `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 1):

Some combination of the following might work. This, I believe, was the old way to do it (though I never did it myself). I was under the impression that `pytest` uses the concept of fixtures to make direct `teardown()` unnecessary.

```
#clear current db session
db.session.remove()
#drop all tables in db
db.drop_all()
#remove app_context
app.app_context.pop()
```

See [this blog post on pytest](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/) for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a solution but does not involve tearing down the flask app. I do not prefer tearing it down for every test case, as that would itself lead to increased uptime for every test case ( unless the flask app initialization is unique to every test case )

Since tests run parallely in pytest, you can do the following

```
try:
    app
except NameError:
    app.config.from_object(TestConfig)
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            init_app(app)
else:
    print("App is already configured. Let us proceed with the test case")
```

You can wrap this around a singleton class instead of taking the above approach as well

Comment: If test state carries between unit tests, idempotency is lost and surprising behavior can occur. So there's a tradeoff between speed and ease of writing on one hand and safety on the other. Obviously pretty use-case dependent.